# Issue with printing the array elements when array is greater than 8

Tags: c++, quicksort

```
//read the elements of the array
cout<<"Enter all the elements of the array"<<endl;
for(j=0;j<size;j++)
  cin>>arr[j];

//populate the elements of the array
cout<<endl<<"Entered elements are as follows"<<endl;
for(j=0;j<size;j++)
 cout<<arr[j]<<"  ";
```

The code is compiled with gcc.
When I run the code in ubuntu 14.04 and enter an array size larger than 8 I don't get any output.

```
> kv@kv:~/c_quizzes$ g++ quick_sort.c 
> kv@kv:~/c_quizzes$ ./a.out 
> Enter the size of the array 
  12 
> Enter all the elements of the array 
  1 22 32 11 212 32323 9839 09 0 -90 99 9 
> Entered elements are as follows

 ^C 
> kv@kv:~/c_quizzes$
```

Comment: Rephrased the question. Formatted the output for readability.

Comment: The most important part is missing. I can only assume that the type of your `size` or `j` or both is `char`?

Please update your question and add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what is value of size and j???

Comment: Try giving a MCVE.    What is the definition of `arr`?

Comment: const int MAX = 10000;int arr[MAX],low,high,size,j; value of size 12